# Gatsby / Docker causes MaxListenersExceededWarning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, gatsby

I am having a really weird issue here.

Firstly when I run local build on my pc with `Gatsby Build` I don't have any errors but as soon as the build starts inside of the Docker environment of our external agency Gatbsy throws this error:

```
error 26-Oct-2020 23:41:19 error (node:8878) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

But the build passes since this is not stopping it from finishing the build so at the end we have a success message from Gatsby:

```
build   26-Oct-2020 23:42:21    The following pages will be precached:
build   26-Oct-2020 23:42:21    /offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback/index.html
build   26-Oct-2020 23:42:21    success onPostBuild - 0.046s
build   26-Oct-2020 23:42:21    info Done building in 65.88 sec
```

Which is good, but then Immediately this happens in Docker:

```
error   26-Oct-2020 23:42:32    
Unable to publish artifact [Code]: 
Unable to publish artifact Required shared artifact: 
[Code], pattern: [**/**] for PRIVATE-JOB via com.atlassian.bamboo.build.artifact.S3ArtifactHandler@4d1aff73 
error   26-Oct-2020 23:42:32    The artifact is required, build will now fail.
simple  26-Oct-2020 23:42:32    The artifact hasn't been successfully published after 8.939 s
```

They are saying it could be because of an EventEmitter memory leak but I don't have that error during the builds on my local machine so it's nearly impossible to debug it.

Does anyone have any idea at all what could cause this issue, could it be a Node.js version mismatch?